# How to transpose the table by keeping the header names

Tags: r, tidyverse

I simplified my previous question. Apologies for the inconvenience. 
How to transpose the table by keeping the header names. I can not achieve this by using `t()` either.

```
q <- tribble(
  ~name, ~g1, ~g2, ~g3,
  "t1", 0,  1,  2,
  "t1", 2,  2,  2,
  "t2", 1,  2,  3,
  "t2", 3,  3,  3,
  "t4", 4,  4,  4
)


q %>%
  rownames_to_column %>% 
  gather(row, value, -rowname) %>% 
  spread(rowname, value)
```

Desired output

```
name    t1    t1    t2    t2    t4
g1     0     2     1     3     4
g2     1     2     2     3     4
g3     2     2     3     3     4
```

Comment: What bits of w are matching the bits of q?

Comment: first row of q with first column of w. @Spacedman

Comment: I think you could transpose table `q` first, dropping the `no` column, setting the column names to `t`, and moving the rownames into a `name` column.

It is a bit unsettling to me for the desired output to have multiple `t2` columns, though.

Comment: @Hao Ye. The `t2` was a mistake. I corrected it now. I tried `t()` but it doesn't keep the row names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create "t#" named columns using `spread` from the `tidyr` package, note that it does so in alphabetical order, & doesn't deal well with duplicated column names.

Your example has two rows named "t1" & two rows named "t2". So that need to be handled.

The names *are* in alphabetical order in this example, but assuming that's not always going to be the case, you can preface the names with a sequence of numbers in running order.

Something like the following could be modified to work:

```
qt <- q %>%
  # make row names unique & sorted correctly in increasing order
  # by appending numbers in running order
  mutate(name = paste(seq(1, n()),
                      name,
                      sep = "_")) %>%
  gather(row, value, -name) %>% 
  spread(name, value)

# strip away the appended numbers from the newly created column names
names(qt) <- sapply(strsplit(names(qt), "_"), function(x){x[2]})

> qt
# A tibble: 3 x 6
   `NA`    t1    t1    t2    t2    t4
* <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    g1     0     2     1     3     4
2    g2     1     2     2     3     4
3    g3     2     2     3     3     4
```

Alternatively, if you don't need a `tidyverse` solution:

```
# transpose the data frame without the name column
qt <- t(q[-1]) 

# add name column back as a dimname attribute
attr(qt, "dimnames")[[2]] <- unname(unlist(q[1]))
# edit: alternative to above
colnames(qt) <- q[1][[1]]

# convert result to data frame
qt <- as.data.frame(qt)

> qt
   t1 t1 t2 t2 t4
g1  0  2  1  3  4
g2  1  2  2  3  4
g3  2  2  3  3  4
```

Whichever it is, I hope this is for presentation rather than analysis, because it's really hard to work with duplicated column names in tidyverse.

Comment: thank you. What if I do not have duplicate column names?

Comment: @user1883491 If you don't have duplicate column names, everything will work just the same. :)

Comment: I think your second line in your base R version overcomplicates things - it could be `colnames(qt)=q$name`

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks! I was looking at `str(qt)`, saw `attr(...)`, & forgot about the `colnames()` option. =p The RHS was about trying to avoid hardcoding the column name, though now that I think about it, there are cleaner ways to do it.